# AbstractBaseUser 'is_staff' field being omitted during syncdb

Tags: django-models, django-admin, django-users

I've decided to create a custom user model for an app by extending Django's AbstractBaseUser along with the PermissionsMixin class. For some reason when I run syncdb or sqall, the `is_staff` field on my model is omitted from the query. As you know, the `is_staff` field is required to be able to access the Admin interface. Here's my code snippet(Django 1.5.8):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import ( \
AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin)

#models.py snippet
class FooUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    #foo fields here...
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='account is activated')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='staff account')
```

I've looked at the source code of the two classes and neither of them implement the `is_staff` field so I'm not sure what the issue is. The only reason why I'm using AbstractBaseUser instead of AbstractUser(which has the `is_staff` field) is because I don't need or want the first, last name fields in my user model. Adding other fields such as `is_admin` worked just fine but this particular field just won't budge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code was the cause of the omission:

```
@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin
```

By commenting it out, the issue was fixed. Alternatively you can also do this:

```
#models.py snippet
class FooUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    #foo fields here...
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='account is activated')
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='staff account')

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
return self.is_admin
```

Full example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example